# Why does my upper function work in MySQL Workbench but not in Java/JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a table of lowercase words in MySQL and I want to get a random one. This is the query that I used, which works fine in both MySQL and Java:

```
select word from words order by rand() limit 1
```

However, I also want to get the word as an uppercase string. I tried this:

```
select upper(word) from words order by rand() limit 1
```

And it works perfectly in MySQL Workbench, but when I use `resultSet.getString("word")` in Java it throws an exception:

`SQL Exception: Column 'word' not found.`

Why does this happen and how can I fix it? I could just convert it to uppercase in Java but I want to know why this is happening.

Comment: `SELECT UPPER(word) FROM words ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` could you try this?

Comment: @ShivaShinde - Nope, that doesn't work either. Also, isn't that exactly what I have already? The capitalization shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I figured it out.

In the result set, the column name is now `upper(word)` instead of  `word`.

So I either need to change my query to:

```
select upper(word) as `word` from words order by rand() limit 1
```

Or change my Java code to:

```
resultSet.getString("upper(word)")
```

Comment: Or use the column index, i.e `resultSet.getString(1)`.